# OpenGraph - Setting expiry?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml

So, on facebook, the ticker shows recent stories from views to my site,
now, what would i need to do to make the ticker display the fact that someone is 'viewing' a post.

Anything i try just ends up saying 'viewed' a post. 
Is there a way to make it say 'is viewing' through opengraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the **Start Time** (in the past) and the **End Time** (in the future).

**Expires In** can be used instead of **End Time** if you prefer that.

While the user is still on your web page (viewing a post) you can regularly [update the action](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#update) to keep it from expiring.

If you for example assume that it takes at least 2 minutes for a user to read a post, you can do this:

**When the user first opens the web page:**

- Create the action with start_time=now and expires_in=120
- Save the action ID for future updates

**Every minute the user is still on the web page:**

- Update the action with expires_in=120